# JPA Entity Graph

Tags: java, jpa, entitygraph

I have an entity like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACQ_OPERATION")
@Getter
@Setter
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "acquiringoperation-entity-graph",
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("cardData"),
        }
)
public class AcquiringOperation extends GenericEntity<Long> {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "card_data_id")
    private CardData cardData;

    ...
}
```

As you can see CardData entity has a FetchType.LAZY fetch type. I want to fetch AcquiringOperation with CardData in one query with left join.

When I try to get data with JPQL

```
EntityGraph<AcquiringOperation> entityGraph = (EntityGraph<AcquiringOperation>) dataService.getEntityManager().getEntityGraph("acquiringoperation-entity-graph");

    acquiringOperations = dataService.getEntityManager().createQuery("select p from AcquiringOperation p", AcquiringOperation.class)
            .setHint("jakarta.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph)
            .getResultList().stream().limit(10).collect(toList());
```

I got n+1 queries

For AcquiringOperation entity

```
select
    acquiringo0_.id as id1_1_,
    ...
from
    ncs_core.acq_operation acquiringo0_
```

and for query for CardData for every record

```
select
    carddata0_.id as id1_5_0_,
    ...
from
    ncs_core.card_data carddata0_ 
where
    carddata0_.id=?
```

On another hand when I'm using repository for data fetching

```
public interface AcquiringOperationRepository extends BaseRepository<AcquiringOperation> {
    @Override
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"cardData"})
    List<AcquiringOperation> findAll();
}

acquiringOperations = acquiringOperationRepository.findAll().stream().limit(10).collect(toList());
```

t works like a charm with one "left joined query"

```
select
    ...
    carddata1_.year as year6_5_1_ 
from
    ncs_core.acq_operation acquiringo0_ 
left outer join
    ncs_core.card_data carddata1_ 
        on acquiringo0_.card_data_id=carddata1_.id
```

I want to use JPQL or QDSL queries. How can I do this with JPA Entity Graph?

Comment: 1. Nonsense. If you use the repo there will be no join since the `@ManyToOne` is marked as lazy. 2. limit(10) in the streaming operation only throws away the results of the query. Anything on stackover get's nothing from me.

Comment: How the relationships are fetched when specified in an EntityGraph is not defined in JPA - you can still get N+1 queries depending on your provider and settings. If you want to force an outer join on the query to fetch the relationship, you should use a fetch Join in the query itself, while some providers (EclipseLink) allow you to specify fetch joins and nested fetch joins as query hints. Hibernate usually does eager fetch as joins though, so if the spring EntityGraph annotation works but the hint doesn't - check that you are using jakarta.persistence and not javax.persistence.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your mention about javax vs jakarta. I'll try to check this idea. Now I'm using javax